# What is the theoretical setup needed to make a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, experimental-physics, estimation

What is the theoretical setup needed to make a black hole?

Firstly sorry for the broad-ended question. I recently came across this statement from this [website](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/b/black+hole#:%7E:text=In%20theory%2C%20any%20mass%20can,sphere%20about%202.5%20km%20across.).

> "In theory, any mass can be compressed sufficiently to form a black hole. The only requirement is that its physical size is less than the Schwarzschild radius. For example, our Sun would become a black hole if its mass was contained within a sphere about 2.5 km across."

I was wondering if it is somehow possible (in real life) to make a black hole (whether that be a micro black hole). Assuming an infinite budget and resources would it be possible to compress matter to its Schwarzschild radius to make it a black hole? What will be the factors I need to consider?

I am imagining some sort of press to compress the matter or maybe some sort of high-energy particle collider.

Answer (score 2):

There is no physical way of applying enough pressure to a bowling ball (to take a convenient example) to squeeze it that hard. Any tool or apparatus for compressing a bowling ball that was made out of ordinary matter would crumble just like the ball. Chemical explosions are too weak, even an atomic bomb going off would only vaporize the ball long before it could compress it enough.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, if enough energy is concentrated in a small enough volume then an artificial black hole could be created - this is known as a [Kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)).

However, this is purely theoretical because creating such a concentration of energy is many orders of magnitude beyond current technology. One estimate is that it would require a particle accelerator 1,000 light years in diameter.

It is also possible that quantum effects might allow a smaller particle accelerator to create quantum black holes. These would be very short lived and would quickly evaporate into high energy particles due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation).

Comment: In the 1970's I read a science fiction story about a particle accelerator that created tiny black holes. They fell through the floor of the accelerator and started orbiting inside the earth. This was before Hawking radiation was known, so the only possible outcome was they would eat the Earth. Fortunately, a couple heroic scientists invented a time machine. They sent messages back in time to warn people not to turn it on. In a subplot, an experiment with an extremely dangerous virus was placed in orbit to prevent any chance of escape. Unfortunately the satellite came out of orbit somehow, and

Comment: burned up on reentry. The virus survived, causing a world wide plague. The time machine saved the day there too. I would swear it was written by Vernor Vinge, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @mmesser314, The folk on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ love "story identification" questions. In this case though, Maybe I can save you the trouble. Your story sounds like ["Thrice Upon a Time" by James P. Hogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrice_Upon_a_Time).